# Task: get current opened file's parent directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, task

I'm writing a task in VS Code, and I'd like to get (just) the name of the parent directory of the current file.  Task has the ${fileDirname} variable substitution, but that returns the entire path.  Is there a variable that returns just the parent?

Comment: Only `${workspaceRootFolderName}` functions in that manner.

Comment: Unfortunately, as the name implies, it only returns the root.  When I have a nested folder structure, like /root/level2/level3/level4/test.txt, I want to get "level4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${fileDirnameBasename}` should be in v1.52.  To get the current file's parent directory.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78316#issuecomment-723995481